# How can we obtain the same number by taking Roman Numerals?

Tags: knuth, taocp, mmix

On page 2 of The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1, Fascicle 1, Knuth (2005) writes, "The same number may also be obtained in a simpler way by taking Roman Numerals."

This is part of Knuth's humorous explanation of the identifying number of the MMIX Computer. The number 2009 is the average of the identifying numbers of 14 other computers. He goes on to say that we can also obtain 2009 by "taking Roman Numerals." How?

I have tried taking the Roman Numerals from the names of the 14 other computers. The sum exceeds 2009 and is far less than 28,126, so neither the sum nor the average work. Knuth could just mean to take the Roman Numerals of MMIX, and if that's it, then fine. Is there something else though? I would love to know.

P.S.

Moderators, this question might not meet SO standards. In that case, please teach me where or how else to ask this question. That way I can better meet the community.

References

Knuth, D. E. (2005). The art of computer programming: Volume 1, fascicle 1 : MMIX, a RISC computer for the new millennium. Upper Saddle River, New Jersey: Addison-Wesley.

Comment: The average of all computer type MMIX number is always 2009 because MMIX in Roman number is 2009

Comment: @FeliceM So, it's just the Roman numeral interpretation of MMIX. Fair enough. I was searching for something that isn't there.

Comment: There is nothing else. M= 1000, IX=9, M+M+IX=2009 it is a trick